# Moving a pop-up application window moves main window on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, window, interface

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.  When I have an application open and  and then  open any pop-up window of that application moving the pop-up moves the main window with the pop-up.

I would like to move the pop-up window off of the main window to see how the actions and setting in the pop-up affect the main application.

How do I separate the moving action of the pop-up from the main window?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  Indeed setting "pop-up windows attached to the main window" as default is a poor design.  20.04 made a lot of nice improvements over earlier versions of ubuntu,  but not in this design that caused a pop-up to always block the a main window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because the pop-up windows are attached to the main window

This can be prevented for some applications using Gnome Tweaks Tool.

Install it using

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then go to the `Windows` section and turn off `Attach Modal Dialogs`

[image]

Comment: It would have been so much better to set as default that one can move the popup window independent to the main window.  This was the default in earlier versions of Ubuntu,  that is the naturally way.  Not sure why ubuntu20.04 would have changed this default into something that does NOT make sense at all!!!  (So many times a popup window simply blocks what you need to see in the main window for further action,  but you cannot move away that silly popup window to see the needed instructions on the main window!)

Comment: Forgot to say: Thank you for your nice and helpful reply!