# When moving a file explorer opened from an application, it always moves and covers the application that opened it

Tags: files, browser, dialog

When moving a file explorer opened from an application, it always moves and covers the application that opened it when I move it.

This is really annoying since sometimes I want to open an html document while looking at the currently open webpage.

Or I am searching for a .cpp file and I need to look at the code in Sublime while browsing for a .cpp or .hpp file. However the file browser that it opens keeps on covering the code! When I try to move it out of the way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving a pop-up application window moves main window on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341341/moving-a-pop-up-application-window-moves-main-window-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. You have to use Gnome-tweaks to modify the windows settings as shown here:

[Moving a pop-up application window moves main window on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341341/moving-a-pop-up-application-window-moves-main-window-on-ubuntu-20-04)